# I need to know if a JOIN query is possible

Tags: mariadb

I have one table like this:

[image: urlalias]

And one like this:

[image: status]

What I want to do is select that "1" from status in the second table if the product_id number matches the number in the query column in the first table and is prefixed by product_id=. category_id and others should be ignored. Is something like this even possible?

Comment: Hi there- welcome to the site! The join is possible, but the specific implementation will depend on which DBMS you are using. Can you please add a tag indicating your platform? (SQL Server, Oracle, Sqlite, mysql etc)

Answer (score 1):

I used Magier's example to come up with this:

```
SELECT oc_url_alias.keyword, oc_product.status, oc_product.date_modified,
REPLACE(query, 'product_id=', '') AS keymatch
FROM oc_url_alias
JOIN oc_product on REPLACE(query, 'product_id=', '') = oc_product.product_id
WHERE oc_product.status = 1;
```

which outputs exactly what I need.

Thanks for all the help everyone posted.

Answer (score 0):

Your data does not really look very normalized.

Besides that you could try something like that:

```
select *, REPLACE(query, 'category_id=', '') as s From table1 
join table2 on REPLACE(query, 'category_id=', '') = table2.product_id
```

Comment: I used your example to come up with this:

SELECT oc_url_alias.keyword, oc_product.status, oc_product.date_modified,
REPLACE(query, 'product_id=', '') AS keymatch
FROM oc_url_alias
JOIN oc_product on REPLACE(query, 'product_id=', '') = oc_product.product_id
WHERE oc_product.status = 1;

and it outputs exactly what I need. Thank you!